# Collection repeat angular equivalent

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, infinite-scroll

Is there an equivalent directive for angular thats similar to collection-repeat for ionic? I'm looking for ways to do infinite scroll without taking too much of the dom. Tried the ngInfiniteScroll and the angular ui/ui-scroll.

Comment: Can you provide code of what you tried? I never worked with ionic but repeating over a list is done with ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for directives that handle very large collections with decent performance?

I think what you're looking for is called `Virtual Scroll`. There are a few libraries that do it. I haven't used any yet, but check out [angular-virtual-scroll](https://github.com/stackfull/angular-virtual-scroll) or [angular-vs-repeat](https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat).